# Principal Object to JSON in Spring Security

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-security

While building a Demo app I used JSP while login and next home page. After  "authenticate" function of Authenticator returns "principal" object to home JSP page. 
I used [these tags to fetch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) . Now this is becoming complex to fetch through this, as it wont support JSTL or Anugular. So I need to know how can I convert Principal object to JSON after Authentication is done. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String user = mapper.writeValueAsString(principal);
    System.out.println(user);
```